# Not able to see JQuery Validator Messages behind the control after validating form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

On Page Load... `$(document).ready(function () { $("form").validate(); });`

On Save Button Click Event... `if($('form').valid()) { Saving data here... }`

"Firebug" with Chrome and Firefox shows everything just perfect with `$("form").validate()` and even `$('form').valid()` returns true and false as expected, but can't see error messages behind specific form controls.

*All are in MVC View

Comment: Code is in a cshtml file

Comment: Further clarification: I have added "required" classes to specific textboxes and dropdowns manually.

Comment: @DOM  why you are not using the unobtrusive validation? are you strongly typing the view?

Comment: @3nigma I can not use inbuild unobtrusive validation as I am developing a dynamic app i.e. label, controls and almost everything is coming from database

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Nothing else to place on fidle, the things are just as I have mentioned above

Comment: there is something wrong in the code which is not here.can't say anything without seeing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo... Works the way I want now.

I just removed "jqueryval" bundle ("jquery.validate.js", "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" and "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"), and have manually included "jquery.validate.js".

Everything is just fine now.

Comment: A structured way: Replaced bundle configuration as from : `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*","~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));` to `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));`